# How to auto compile python/c extension?

Tags: python, c

I wrote a python/c extension file lda_model.c

and I added setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

modules = [Extension('c_lda_model', sources=["lda_model.c"])]

setup(ext_modules=modules)
```

Now I have to compile the C code by

```
python setup.py build
```

before running python code where call the C code.

> Is there any way to automatically compile the invoked C extension,
>    while running the python code?

Answer (score 2):

Not with the standard way of writing extensions, which is what you just do. 
However, there are a couple other approaches of writing native code extensions to Python which do compilation in execution time.

One such example is [Weave](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/numerical_sage/weave.html) that comes with Scipy - there are others ways if you look for.